# How I can get last word in the given string without using if condition for index?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Q.Write a python function, encrypt_sentence(msg) which accepts a message and encrypts it based on rules given below and returns the encrypted message.

Words at odd position -> Reverse It

Words at even position -> Rearrange the characters so that all consonants appear before the vowels and their order should not change

Note: Assume that the sentence would begin with a word and there will be only a single space between the words.

Perform case sensitive string operations wherever necessary.

```
#Rearranging the characters so that all consonants appear before the vowels and their order should not change

def consonants_vowels(str):


    vowels_string = "aAeEiIoOuU"  # all Vowels in lowercase and uppercase
    vowel = ""
    consonants = ""

    for i in range(0, len(str)):
        if str[i] in vowels_string:
            vowel = vowel + str[i]          #adding vowels
        else:
            consonants += str[i]            #adding consonants

    return consonants + vowel + " "  # " " to make space between words


str = "How to resolve"

count = 1

word = ""

final_string = ""

for i in range(0, len(str)):

    if str[i] != " " and i + 1 != len(str): #getting each word from string

        word += str[i]

    else:

        if count % 2 != 0:    #to check word at odd postion

            final_string += word[::-1] + " "    #reversing string at odd position

        else:

            final_string = final_string + consonants_vowels(word)

        count += 1
        word = ""

print(final_string)
```

Expected Output: `woH to evloser`

Code Output: `woH to vloser`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a homework service. Please make an effort to solve the question and ask here about specific problems you can't figure out.

Comment: also isn't this obfuscation and NOT encryption? usually for encryption there are keys and stuff, this also doesn't change any characters

Comment: @Matiiss VERY good point. https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding-encryption-hashing-obfuscation/

And Google's "Answer" Obfuscation, also referred to as beclouding, is to hide the intended meaning of the contents of a file, making it ambiguous, confusing to read, and hard to interpret. Encryption is to actually transform the contents of the file, making it unreadable to anyone unless they apply a special key.

So, this would be encryption, since a special key is required and without it the "program" or the message, in this case, cannot be "executed" or in the case of a message, understood

Answer (score 0):

This took me a minute, but the answer to your question is a matter of debugging step by step(stepping through your program one step at a time until something happens that you wouldn't expect / something breaks).

In this case, the issue is on your last loop of a letter. That is when you check if `i + 1 !- len(str)` Your problem being that you only add the letter `str[i]` to `word` IFF `i != len(str)` but of course `i+1 == len(str)` on the last execution of the loop, so it doesn't ever add the `e` to the word, and thus, as we would expect, when it reverses the word (which it does correctly) there is also no `e`

There are surely a few ways around this, but here is how I would do it:

First of all we DO want the letter to be added when `i = len(str)` - in your example text, i = 13, so we'll take the +1 away from that line.

Next, we need to run the loop Once more After that i = 13 loop (the one that added the `e`) so that we can check if we are done (that is, `if i >= len(str)` or in other words we check if it isn't -- `<` -- then drop to the else since that -- `14 < 14` is now false. So we'll take that `+1` from earlier and stick it in the number of times the loop is going to execute -- `for i in range(0, len(str)+1):` So this will be when i = 14 (which is out of the index for `str`) so...

We also need to swap the conditionals in the `and` because `str[i]` when `i = 14` will throw an error since there isn't a 15th item (index of 14) in a string of length 14.

Here is the final, working, code. Hope the explanation helped you understand how to do this in the future.

```
#Rearranging the characters so that all consonants appear before the vowels and their order should not change
def consonants_vowels(str):
    vowels_string = "aAeEiIoOuU"  # all Vowels in lowercase and uppercase
    vowel = ""
    consonants = ""
    for i in range(0, len(str)):
        if str[i] in vowels_string:
            vowel = vowel + str[i]          #adding vowels
        else:
            consonants += str[i]            #adding consonants
    return consonants + vowel + " "  # " " to make space between words

str = "How to resolve"
count = 1
word = ""
final_string = ""

for i in range(0, len(str)+1):
    if i < len(str) and str[i] != " " : #getting each word from string
        word += str[i]
    else:
        if count % 2 != 0:    #to check word at odd postion
            final_string += word[::-1] + " "    #reversing string at odd position
        else:
            final_string = final_string + consonants_vowels(word)
        count += 1
        word = ""
        
print(final_string)
```

[image]